# Json.NET cannot serialize a string with white spaces properly

Tags: c#-4.0, json.net

I have a method ends with

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyValue);
```

Let's say **MyValue** is "value", the result is

```
[{"Data1":"value"}]
```

which is an expected output. however if **MyValue** is "value to be serialized", the result becomes

> [{"Data1":"value" to="" be="" serialized"}]

I tried other types and they are working fine except if the value to be serialized is a string containing white spaces, the result is different. I think I'm missing something very simple..

Comment: I don't think serialization is the problem; Json.Net handles this case  just fine as you can see [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IacChn).  You must have something else going on in your code.  Can you make a fiddle which demonstrates your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
class NewClass
{
    public NewClass() { }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Data1")]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}


List<NewClass> lst= new List<NewClass>() { new NewClass(){MyProperty = "value to be serialized"} };

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst);
```

This works fine.

Explanation : MyValue is a list of Key Value pair as in [{"Data1":"value"}]. The class NewClass has property with the name "Data1" and value "value to be serialized". JsonConvert.SerializeObject would return [{"Data1":"value to be serialized"}] as expected.

Comment: Providing some explanation would be very helpful!

Comment: Just let me know how you tried to implement. Just a rough code.